# Automatic updates of unlisted applications in the Apple App store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Recently I published my first Unlisted application on the App Store. Only people with a link can download it.

My problem is, when I release an update, people who have downloaded it using the link aren't getting notified that there is an update. Furthermore, users who have enabled automatic updates aren't getting them either.

To update the app, you have to go through the link again and update it manually.

I can't find anywhere if this is considered normal behavior. I have also contacted the Apple support team.

Comment: Have you used TestFlight?

Comment: @Raptor If I understand correctly, you are asking if the app is still in its testing phase. The app has been published. The link was provided by Apple upon being successfully released on the App Store.

Comment: No. The link you described is called TestFlight distribution (https://testflight.apple.com/) unless you are using an Enterprise Developer account.

Comment: @Raptor, No, they are using an [unlisted app](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment/dep36d738732/web)

Comment: @EnCoder it's been a while since I released an update to my unlisted app, but I can't recall any update issues.   If they don't have the link, they can find the app in their "purchased" apps

Comment: I don't have a view as to whether this is normal behaviour, but for your userbase, do you have their email addresses anyway? If so, could you email update instructions to them? (I assume this is a temporary problem that you will resolve when the app is listed normally).